Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to SGELSY. RuntimeError: false INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED
Environment:

CPU: AMD r5 5600h
Memory: 16G
GPU: rtx3050
Python: 3.9.19
Pytorch: 2.2.2
Numpy: 1.24.3

Errors:
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to SGELSY. 

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to SGELSY. 

...(many times)

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to SGELSY. 

coef = torch.linalg.lstsq(mat.to(device), y_eval.unsqueeze(dim=2).to(device),
driver='gelsy' if device == 'cpu' else 'gels').solution[:, :, 0]

RuntimeError: false INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "C:\\actions-runner\\_work\\pytorch\\pytorch\\builder\\windows\\pytorch\\aten\\src\\ATen\\native\\BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp":1540, please report a bug to PyTorch. torch.linalg.lstsq: (Batch element 0): Argument 6 has illegal value. Most certainly there is a bug in the implementation calling the backend library.

I tried changing the numpy version to 1.23 or 1.26, and also tried changing the pytorch version, including the cpu and gpu versions, but both didn't work. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? How should I deal with it?

What is mat and y_eval? Can you provide the contents?

@FlyingTeller When the program runs normally, the values of mat and y_eval are (as an example): mat: tensor([[[1.6660e-01, 6.6667e-01, 1.6673e-01, 4.1113e-13, 0.0000e+00], … [0.0000e+00, 2.4998e-13, 1.6672e-01, 6.6667e-01, 1.6661e-01]]], grad_fn=) y_eva: tensor([[ 0.0032, -0.0100, -0.0085], ..., [ 0.0053, 0.0233, 0.0148]]) Before the error occurs, the value of mat looks fine, but the value of y_eval becomes: tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan], … [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=)

@FlyingTeller The value of y_eval comes from the function y_eval = coef2curve(x_pos, self.grid, self.coef, self.k). When errors occur, the value of self.coef changes from tensor([[-0.0048, -0.0124,  0.0192, -0.0056, -0.0031],
...,
[-0.0063, -0.0208,  0.0124,  0.0095,  0.0013]], requires_grad=True)(as an example)
to tensor([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
...,
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]], requires_grad=True) Why it happens?
.
